# What kind of a dependency that between these customer and project manager?

Tags: project-management-style, dependencies, customer

In the middle of the activity sequencing process, project manager has identified that the execution activity cannot be started until the hardware required to do the testing is available (this hardware will be provided by the customer). What kind of a dependency that we have between these two activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Activity B cannot begin before Activity A is complete, it's a **finish-start** dependency, in PM-speak.

Alternatively, if both activities have to start at the same time (pretty rare), it's a start-start dependency.

If both activities have to end at the same time, it's a finish-finish dependency.

Comment: Finish start dependency.